# MQ SSL Connection from .Net: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate (0x80090327)

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, tls1.2, client-certificates

I'm trying to connect to an MQ Server (vserion 9.2) using the .Net library. I tried both amqmdnet.dll for .Net Framework and amqmdnetstd.dll for .Net 6.0 and I'm getting the same error.

The server requires a TLS 1.2 connection using Cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and a client certificate. I received the client certificate: a .p12 file generated from the .kdb Java file. The certificate has been placed into the user certificate store, personnal. I changed as well the Cipher to have the required Cipher in first position in Windows (using gpedit, SSL Cipher suite order).

Here is the code (the one using amqmdnetstd.dll)

```
    Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
    properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, SERVER_IP);
    properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, SERVER_PORT);
    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, SERVER_CHANNEL);
    properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*USER");
    properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
    properties.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, "ibmwebspheremqmyuser");

    MQQueueManager _mqmgmt = new MQQueueManager(SERVER_QUEUEMNG, properties);
```

When the `MQQueueManager` is being created, I see this exception in the MQ traces and it returns with a 2393 error code

```
0000018C 08:13:12.004980   436.1       Created an instance of SSLStreams
0000018D 08:13:12.005002   436.1       Setting current certificate store as 'User'
0000018E 08:13:12.005010   436.1       Windows/Mac so use My Store  & CurrentStore
0000018F 08:13:12.005043   436.1       Created store object to access certificates
00000190 08:13:12.009208   436.1       Opened store
00000191 08:13:12.009230   436.1       Accessing certificate - ibmwebspheremqmyuser
00000192 08:13:12.009736   436.1       Adding certificate with FriendlyName - ibmwebspheremqmyuser
00000193 08:13:12.009770   436.1       Number of certificates in the store:1
00000194 08:13:12.010241   436.1       TLS12 supported - True
00000195 08:13:12.010262   436.1       TLS13 supported - True
00000196 08:13:12.010456   436.1       Cipherspec protocol version:TLS 1.2
00000197 08:13:12.010745   436.1       Setting SslProtol as Tls12
00000198 08:13:12.010760   436.1       Starting SSL Authentication
00000199 08:13:12.011550   436.1       Server name is set to XXX
0000019A 08:13:12.013051   436.1      ------------{  MQEncryptedSocket.FixClientCertificate(Object,String,X509CertificateCollection,X509Certificate,String[])
0000019B 08:13:12.013086   436.1       Client callback has been invoked to find client certificate
0000019C 08:13:12.013112   436.1      ------------}  MQEncryptedSocket.FixClientCertificate(Object,String,X509CertificateCollection,X509Certificate,String[]) rc=OK
0000019D 08:13:12.043400   436.1      ------------{  MQEncryptedSocket.FixClientCertificate(Object,String,X509CertificateCollection,X509Certificate,String[])
0000019E 08:13:12.043430   436.1       Client callback has been invoked to find client certificate
0000019F 08:13:12.043436   436.1       Use the first certificate that is from an acceptable issuer.
000001A0 08:13:12.043579   436.1      ------------}  MQEncryptedSocket.FixClientCertificate(Object,String,X509CertificateCollection,X509Certificate,String[]) rc=OK
000001A1 08:13:12.090685   436.1       System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090327): An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket.MakeSecuredConnection()
000001A2 08:13:12.091000   436.1       New MQException CompCode: 2 Reason: 2393
```

I tried to use a dummy certificate instead. In this case the connection is done but after I'm getting a 2540 error code most likely because the user authenticated with my dummy certificate doesn't have access to the required channel.

I cannot figure what's wrong when using this certificate. Any idea is welcome !

Thanks

UPDATE 1
Finally, I was able to connect to the server without changing my configuration or code. The issue was on MQ Server side, the configuration was not correct (at least the user associated to the my client certificate was not setup correctly).

Comment: Do you have the full cert (private and public keys) installed?  Do you have the issuer and root certs in the user cert store? You said the server is at 9.2, what is the full version of the DLLs you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that the certificate I have (.p12 file) is the private key, but I don't have anything more. And you're right the issuer is not trusted because I see `This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.` in certification path of the certificate properties. What I don't understand on this certificate is that the "Issued by" and "Issued to" fields are the same: it's "myuser"

Comment: Version of amqmdnetstd.dll is 9.3.4.0

Comment: That's called a self-signed certificate, and unless you specifically allow it (and you shouldn't) it will not be accepted. You need a *proper* certificate issued by a Certificate Authority, either your own private one (if you have) or pay a public CA. The certificate of that CA must be in the Trusted Root list. That's for both the server and client (assuming the client also requires it). Often client certs are generated by a private CA, which can then be used to authenticate to an AD domain or Azure.